# How to get a timestamp value from SQLite

Tags: core-data, sqlite

My coredata sqlite table "SQLTABLE" contains a tuple of type timestamp "ZTIMESTAMP" as 123456789

How can I read it using **sql** (not obj C) and convert it to a date ?

Comment: What you tried so far.?What would be the output if "ZTIMESTAMP" is 123456789.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M', ZTIMESTAMP, 'unixepoch') as time from SQLTABLE
```

Sqlite allows you to format time that is a UNIX time timestamp.
You can test this in a SQL Browser tool locally. To check your query and I think you can change "unixepock" to "local-time" for the time in your local time.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to get correct date out of it.
If I put in unixepoch the time is shown to be 10 yrs back 
If not then it is shown to be 40 years ahead

Comment: I think we are getting close, can you paste an actual time stamp value in and what you think it should be.  You probably can add some value to the timestamp to make it work correctly, once you figure out what the timestamp is and what it should be.

Comment: Just resolved it , the issue was some additional constant value being added to the the original timestamp.
Thanks

Comment: Say @Ecko123, can you share how you adjusted for said constant? What was it?